# Vue JS Contact Form Error "Cannot read property 'post' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js

I am getting the cannot read property 'post' of undefined error but I am not sure where my error is exactly. I am hoping someone can spot something I am missing since I am new to Vue JS. Thank you in advance.

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from '../router';
import './assets/css/style.css'
import './assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './assets/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css';


Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Nav></Nav>
    <router-view />
    <Footer></Footer>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Nav from "./components/Nav";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
export default {
  components: {
    Nav,
    Footer
  }
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
}
</style>
```

In my local DEV environment, I am getting a similar error but the word 'name' shows up instead of 'post'
After the build, I get the error Cannot read property 'post'.

Contact.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <section class="page-section" id="contact">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <h2 class="section-heading text-uppercase">Contact Us</h2>
            <h3 class="section-subheading text-white">We are ready to get your project up and live.</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div v-if="sent">
              <h3
                class="text-white"
              >Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.</h3>
            </div>
            <form @submit="onSubmit" class="contact">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input
                      class="form-control"
                      id="name"
                      type="text"
                      placeholder="Your Name *"
                      required
                      data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name."
                      v-model="contact.name"
                    />
                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input
                      class="form-control"
                      id="email"
                      type="email"
                      placeholder="Your Email *"
                      required
                      data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address."
                      v-model="contact.email"
                    />
                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input
                      class="form-control"
                      id="phone"
                      type="tel"
                      placeholder="Your Phone"
                      data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number."
                      v-model="contact.phone"
                    />
                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea
                      class="form-control"
                      id="message"
                      placeholder="Your Message *"
                      required="required"
                      data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."
                      v-model="contact.message"
                    ></textarea>
                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                  <div id="success"></div>
                  <button
                    id="sendMessageButton"
                    class="btn tell-me btn-xl text-uppercase"
                    type="submit"
                  >
                    Send
                    Message
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      sent: false,
      contact: {
        name: "",
        email: "",
        phone: "",
        message: ""
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    /**
     * Clear the form
     */

    clearForm() {
      for (let field in this.contact) {
        this.contact[field] = "";
      }
    },

    /**
     * Handler for submit
     */

    onSubmit(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();

      this.isSending = true;

      setTimeout(() => {
        // Build for data
        let form = new FormData();
        for (let field in this.contact) {
          form.append(field, this.contact[field]);
        }

        // Send form to server
        this.$http
          .post("http://rrspark.com/send_form_email.php", form)
          .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            this.clearForm();
            this.isSending = false;
          })
          .catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
          });
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
};
</script>
<style lang="">
</style>
```

In the root directory
send_form_email.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "info@rrspark.com";
    $email_subject = "Email from website's contact form";

    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }


    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['message'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }



    $first_name = $_POST['name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['message']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

 if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";


    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }



    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->
<h3>
Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.
</h3>
<?php

}
?>
```

I am not clear on if I should be using $http or $axios nor how to implement them as I mentioned earlier, I am new to Vue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to install the Axios package.

```
npm i axios
```

otherwise use the vue-resource, like this:

```
import VueResource from "vue-resource"
Vue.use(VueResource);
```

After that you can start using $http without any errors, like this:

```
this.$http.post
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just import axios in main.js and attach it to vue like this and you'll be able to use this.$http from your components.

```
import axios from 'axios'

Vue.prototype.$http = axios;
```

I think axios is recommended in the documentation as well over the standart vue-resource package.

[Using Axios to Consume APIs](http://You%20can%20just%20import%20in%20in%20main.js%20and%20attach%20it%20to%20vue%20like%20this%20and%20you%27ll%20be%20able%20to%20use%20this.$http%20from%20your%20components.%20%20%60%60%60%20import%20axios%20from%20%27axios%27%20%20Vue.prototype.$http%20=%20axios;%20%60%60%60%20%20I%20think%20axios%20is%20recommended%20in%20the%20documentation%20as%20well%20over%20the%20standart%20vue-resource%20package.%20%20%20https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html)